# Asynchronous Processing=true in SignalR connection string

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, connection-string, signalr

I am using SignalR with the following connection string:

```
 <add name="SignalR" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SignalR;Data Source=machine1" />
```

Everything is working fine, but in a specific enviroment SignalR fails telling it needs

```
Asynchronous Processing=true
```

To be added to the connection string.

- Should I blindly add this ? (It has a performance hit
  [SQL Server connection string Asynchronous Processing=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642705/sql-server-connection-string-asynchronous-processing-true))
- What could be causing this to work in one enviroment and fail in the
  other ?

Comment: Are you using the Sql server scaleout backplane

Comment: I have no idea what Sql server scaleout backplane is.

Comment: SignalR doesn't usually use sql server unless you're using one of its scaleout solutions.

Comment: Yes, I use the sql scaleout backplane: GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SignalR"].ConnectionString);