# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, database-connection

I am getting following error when i am trying to connect Production DB from Local Environment.

I was able to connect Production DB before, but suddenly i am getting following error, any idea?

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

I was trying to run asp.net website in local PC, which has connection string of Production DB, following is stack trace for error I am getting in local environment.

```
>    at MyWebsiteDAL.clsForumQuestion.SelectAll(Int32 CurrentPageIndex, Int32 PageSize) in D:\EDrive\My WebSites\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\MyWebsiteDAL\clsForumQuestion.cs:line 821
       at CodeConnect.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\EDrive\My WebSites\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\Default.aspx.cs:line 100
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong here?

Comment: Which DBMS are you connecting to?

Comment: Are you able to connect from the local PC with SSMS?  This question would be better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Yes i can able to connect.  What I observer was suddenly that starts working.

Comment: I believe this question does belong on StackOverflow (and not ServerFault) because the underlying problem causing the error was Asp.net Cassini in Visual Studio.  Stopping all existing Cassini (WebDev.WebServer.exe) instances and re-running the app worked for me.

Comment: @ MikeTeeVee I got the same problem with a simple WinForm application. No cassini involved.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, please follow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137669/5772425

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**Solution**

1) Clean your VS.Net Solution

2) Rebuild Project.

3) Reset IIS

4) Run the project again.

Basically that solved my problem, but in my case i was not getting this error and suddenly my local environment starts giving me above error, so may be that trick work for me.

Comment: I had a similar problem (localhost too). The key point seems maybe to have been point 3. All I seemed to need to do was kill the instance of the VS WebServer (Cassini) and rebuild & hit F5. That solved it for me. Thanks for your answer. (You should consider marking it as the solution)

Comment: This solution also worked for me. I too was using VS Web Server (Cassini) as opposed to IIS just the same as Amadiere.

Comment: This sounds more like a workaround than a fix. I wonder if the real problem has to do with connection pooling.

Comment: Thank you!  It suddenly started giving me this error too.  I was editing an aspx page and debugging when it started throwing this error from one build to the next.  (FYI: I was connecting to SQL Server 2008 Express on Arvixe).  I opened my system-tray and stopped all the "Asp.net Development Server"'s (Cassini).  Re-ran and everything is working again.  Thought I was losing it for a sec.

Comment: I tried all of the above without success.  It took a reboot to get things to work.

Comment: It was worked for me just with 1 & 2 levels. Thanks.

Comment: By "reset IIS" I presume you meant "Restart IIS"? This was the solution for me, no need to do anything in my solution.

Comment: This solution also worked for the following error message:

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid

Thank you!

Comment: Had this again today. All you need to do is run iisreset from an admin command prompt.

Comment: I also put my focus on step 3.  In my case I was using IIS Express.  I first discovered two instances of it running (taskbar system tray).  I exited out of both of these but still got the error.  I then used task manager to kill the iisexpress.exe *32 worker process.  This resolved the issue.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing some possible directions for root cause analysis. Work-arounds have value, but it's more useful to know why this occurs and why the work-around works.

Comment: just resetting iis did it for me

Comment: "Thank you for calling Microsoft Technical Support. Please restart your computer. Thank you, and have a nice day." *click*

Answer (score 177):

In my case this error occurred with dot net core and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.
The solution was to add `;TrustServerCertificate=true` to the end of the connection string.

Comment: This was it when using self-signed certificates

Comment: Yeah thanks I had to do that with the last preview of Visual Studio for Mac 17.3

Comment: Tags: dotnet7 net7 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Effectively, the error occurs because my SQL Server is not set to a valid certificate, forcing me to add this parameter in my connection string.

Comment: It worked for me. The app is built on .NET 6, we started experiencing the issue in one fine morning on a test server. Although https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-affe says "THEN (and only then) you have Windows Authentication happening. Any user id= setting in the connection string will be ignored.", the user specified in the connection string is not being ignored!

Comment: This solved my problem in .net 7

Comment: Indeed only happens with .NET7. Using other projects on .NET6 with identical configurations without issues.

Comment: This solved my problem in .net7 when using macOs

Answer (score 28):

- Save your work,
- Close Visual Studio, then
- Re-open your project

This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I often find making a coffee while it restarts makes all the difference.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with a node server instead. I was running a node server on ubuntu VM guest and accessing from Windows 10 VM host. Pausing and saving the VM, then resetting the Windows 10 host, then opening the VM back up worked, so I assumed it was a problem with Windows, not the local server. But then, I just now tried resetting the local node server, and that fixed it as well...so who knows, ha

Answer (score 20):

Running the following command worked for me:

```
netsh Winsock reset
```

Seen at https://serverfault.com/a/487139/250527

Comment: This resolved my issue. I owe the network guy lunch cause I had thrown him under the bus.

Comment: FYI, this `reset` needs a system restart.

Comment: After 2.5 hours, this saved my bacon.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 18):

I experienced this error when running some very memory-expensive processes. When the system started to run short of memory, I begun to notice this kind of error.
I had to change the algorithm in order to make a better use of RAM.

To be noted that while some threads threw this exception, some other threw:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=43606; handshake=560;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

Both problems disappeared after the system was changed so that it could run using less RAM.

Comment: Confirmed. I ran intensive processing on SQL Server from C# using parallel.foreach on my laptop. My memory usage was at its max. Computer was barely usable for about 15 minutes before i got this error.

Comment: I ran MsSql as container, and had restricted it to 1GB of memory. It worked when I upped the limit to 2GB. Thank you sir ‍♂️

Comment: I agree, this is due to lack of RAM

Comment: More generally, this might occur if your process isn't getting any CPU time. Perhaps because the OS is busy swapping memory as in your example. Perhaps because another CPU heavy program has a higher priority. For example the default priority for scheduled tasks is below normal.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, I was storing session data in the database, the connection string had **Encrypt=True** in it, which I assume told the sql client to connect to the server in secure (SSL) mode, removing this helped!

Comment: This flag will be added to your connection string if you are going to be using a Windows Azure SQL Database. I am pretty certain it will be used for other PaaS/IaaS/Server providers also.

Comment: AzureSQL requiring encrypt true https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2012/03/06/sql-azure-requiring-encrypttrue/

Comment: I believe in this case, you'd be better off adding `TrustServerCertificate=true` to the connection string instead of removing `Encrypt=true`. This was suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62896535/2665754). Based on the [Microsoft docs on this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.1), the SSL certificate validation gets turned on when encrypt is set to true. Trusting the server certificate bypasses that SSL certificate validation.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was:

`Persist Security Info=True;`

in my connection string that needed to be removed.  Once I did that I no longer had issues.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check a few things:

1. You production server allows remote connections. (possible that someone turned this off, especially if you have a DBA)
2. Check your connection string. Sometimes if you are using an ip address or server name this will cause this error. Try both.

Answer (score 5):

If you're connecting to a database in an availability group, then you may need to add `multisubnetfailover=true` to the connection string.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I couldn't connect to a database and tried the recommendations here.

At the end of the day this is what worked for me:

Used the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool to enable the TCP/IP and/or the Named Pipes protocols on the SQL Server client computer.

1. Click Start, point to All Programs, and click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Click to expand SQL Server Network Configuration and then click Client Protocols.
3. Right-click the TCP/IP protocol and then click Enable.
4. Right-click the Named Pipes protocol and then click Enable.
5. Restart the SQL server service if prompted to do so.

I am still not sure why or when this was disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Tried most of the above and nothing worked.  Then turned off the VPN software (NordVPN) and everything was fine.

Comment: in my case i had to disable my antivirus and it worked

Answer (score 3):

As described in the answer of [Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149444/ricardo-stuven) ,

```
netsh Winsock reset
```

has worked for me ,

**P.S.** if you have Internet download manager or such programs which changes you IP Setting is installed then after running this command when you reboot your computer IDM will ask to change setting , Set NO in this case and then run your application it will work correctly.

Hope it

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the exact same problem with no changes to the code base or servers. It turned out to be that the DB server was running at 100% CPU and SQL Server was being starved of any CPU time, which caused the timeout.

Comment: SQL Server is the DB server, right? Or is the DB server just the system in general on which SQL Server is running?

Comment: Is this case the Db server is the physical hardware and SQL Server is the software

Answer (score 2):

I restarted **SQL Server (Sharepoint)** service and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution is to kill zombie IIS express worker processes.

e.g. locate in Task Manager and end task.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried many solutions in the past month, none has worked. The problem is the Production DB is within a VPN and somehow the ISP provider thinks the HTTP connection is not secure. However, I was able to connect to the same Production DB from SSMS (uses TCP).

My solution: use the mobile phone as a hotspot and use mobile data instead of my office/home Wi-Fi.

Comment: Same in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the connection from my API to the DB worked fine when running on my local machine, this error only occurred when running the .NET Core 5 API application in a docker container utilizing base image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`. The problem was a TLS version inconsistency between SQL Server and one of our Dependencies. The fix was to add the following line to the API Dockerfile, downgrading security level of TLS:

RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

This was taken from [this article](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633) wherein the aforementioned `RUN` command was suggested, which fixed my problem. Direct link to the suggested fix is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633#issuecomment-705540363).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was having no luck with the suggested fixes.  I then came across [this article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases#tabs) and saw the comment from Mirrh regarding a program called Sendori blocking the LSP.  No idea how it got on my computer but there it was and removing it fixed the issue.

If the article doesn't work just check your Programs and uninstall Sendori if you see it.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here and no answers listed here worked, nor any solutions I could find online. The issue started shortly after Windows 10 anniversary update got applied on my dev PC and only affected my old SQL Server 2005 instance. I was not able to connect to the instance via my Web Applications or even using Sql Management Studio.

For what it's worth, this is what resolved it for me:

1. **Open SQL Server Configuration Manager** (depending on what version of SQL Server you're running):

   - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager.msc
   - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc OR
   - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc OR
   - etc
2. **Select SQL Server Services**
3. **Locate the troubled service and view Properties**

   - eg SQL Server (SQL2005) in my case
4. **In the Log On tab, change the "Built-in account" to "Network Service"**

Which is almost what this random solution said: http://www.kutayzorlu.com/operating-systems/linux-unix-redhat-debian-ubuntu-opensuse-centos/general-server-administrating/error-fixed-a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-12405.html

I chose Network Service for no reason at all. Mine was already configured to use Local System. This security doesn't matter to me as it was only problematic on my Local development machine, only accessed locally. I can't advise why this works, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was getting the error when i wanted to access a remote database. However, i solved it by starting SQL Server Browser service.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem from many days. I had to explicitly add TLS1.2 support in my core project to address this error and it worked fine. ( ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;)

See below link for more details (thanks to author Usman Khurshid)
https://www.itechtics.com/connection-successfully-established-error-occured-pre-login-handshake/

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to an old SQL Server:

Switch from System.Data.**SqlClient.SqlConnection** to System.Data.**OleDb.OleDbConnection**

Use an OleDb connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Northwind" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=MyServer; Initial Catalog=Northwind;  Persist Security Info=True; User ID=abc; Password=xyz;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using .Net 6 but updated Entity Framework Core Packages to version 7.0. The issue was gone after downgrading the Nuget packages.

Comment: having the same issue moving to EF7 ( with .net6 ).     Adding TrustServerCertificate=true has solved it on local machine.   But deployment to Aws k8s with the same connection string - is still giving the error.  Still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the source of this issue is an inaccurate error message. I'm getting the same message like this, but my mistake was the incorrect port.

Comment: Thanks.. Changed to the right port and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the reason for it was BCrypt.Net library, compiled using .NET 2.0 framework, while the whole project, which used it, was compiling with .NET 4.0. If symptoms are the same, try download [BCrypt source code](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) and rebuild it in *release configuration* within .NET 4.0. After I'd done it "pre-login handshake" worked fine. Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error and did all the suggestions from you guys here but none had any effect for my error.

I caught the culprit: if you are using `*.ini` file for your system, you might want to check what server name was input there and make sure it is the same as the one in your web.config connection string.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, [Re-enabling **TLS 1.0**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2015/07/09/an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake-dbnetlibconnectionopen-secdoclienthandshake-ssl-security-error-when-connecting-to-sql-server/) in the DB server resolved this issue.

Comment: This is not really a solution. I will not downvote it, because in development environments it may help someone, but this exposes serious security threats.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a TLS protocol mismatch between a Raspberry Pi hosting a .Net Core 3.1 app requesting to a Windows Server 2012 with MSSQL. I tried many changes of TLS protocol version on the Windows Server side without any effect. I finally found this post https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/126, indicating modify the client side, ie to update the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` on the RPi side, and that worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had this happen on a HyperV virtual machine that was accessing my database on my local (host) machine.  Basically it all works normally, but after a reboot there is some weird condition  that this error starts coming up from the virtual machine applications.  There is something in the network layer that is getting horribly confused.  However, I have found if I **ping** the virtual server from the host server, it seems to fix the problem (not sure why exactly).  But this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is if you have your SQL Server Network Configuration set to 'Force Encryption'. If you do, you'll get this error unless you do the requisite client incantations for an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

#macusers

I have found new solution without closing the Visual Studio.

1. Go to the terminal.
2. `lsof -i:<PORT_Number>` i.e. 1433 in my case.
3. Outout will be process using that port number
4. Kill those processes using `kill -9 <PID>` i.e. process Id

Please refer Screenshot attached.

[image: commands and respective outputs for killing process]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a wrong port. I connected to the on-prem DB from an Azure App Service via a [Hybrid connection](https://www.cloudcorner.gr/microsoft/azure/azure-app-service-get-data-from-on-premises-databases-securely/) and the connection used one port, but the SQL Server instance used a different port. Make sure all of the ports are matching: connection string, VPN/Proxy/Hybrid connections, SQL Server allowed ports for [each protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-connect-to-the-database-engine).

`sqlcmd` and `ping`/`tcpping` are great tools to test your connectivity before you try changing any code in your app. You can run them both locally and in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I am very very late to post the answer. Also, I have tried all the possibilities  from various blog sites.

The exact error I was facing while connecting **SQL Server 2014 with .net Core 3.1** application.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

To overcome the problem, I have enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2 with Client and Server both entries. (Detailed descriptions can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

and installed SQL Server 2014 SP2 which can be downloaded from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53168

Comment: It is not a matter of being late. The types of causes that can trigger this error are probably changing over time. I think TLS 1.1 being an issue only makes sense now because Microsoft pushed out updates to retire it (along with the older 1.0) during September 2023: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-soon-to-be-disabled-in-windows/ba-p/3887947

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were 2 instances of SQL in my computer: SQL SERVER and SQL EXPRESS. I've stopped sql express service and it worked.