# Error connecting to SQL Server 2005 with ADO.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to connect to our sql server with the following connection string

```
<add name="siteDB" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx\sql_2005;Initial Catalog=Intranet;User ID=username;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but I am getting this error

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake
```

this is only a problem when the Web app is compiled as .net 4, .net 2 seems to work fine

I have tried the following with no success

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```

in the connection string.. no joy

also tried

```
TCP/IP protocols enabled
named pipes enabled
```

using a newly set up account with the correct permissions

any ideas?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ) or
this (worked for me once):

1)  Remove all SSL certificates and encryption options from IIS – both at the website level (for example from the “Default Web Site”) and at virtual directory level. Basically if you enabled encryption put all the settings back to their original non-encrypted settings.

2)  Remove all SSL self-signed certificates from the server. These are the certificates that SelfSSL generated for you. Your server may have genuine certificates – don’t touch these as they may be used by other software and anyway should be harmless.

These certificates need to be removed from all certificates stores. To do this start MMC and (one at a time) add the Certificate Manager snap-in to “My user account”, “Service account” and “Computer account”. Locate every single copy of the self-signed certificates wherever they may be (Personal, Trusted Root Certificates Authorities, etc) and delete them.

3)  Now, although you have deleted the actual certificates, SQL Server still continues to use encryption. This is because it has created a copy of the certificate in the registry. You need to locate these and delete them.

These are located in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.x\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib

AND/OR

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL.x\Client\SuperSocketNetLib

4)  Restart the server and this should have fixed the initial error and you will find that SQL agent is running and things are back to normal.

As found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1006080-149-1.aspx).