# Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Connection error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

[image]

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

Comment: Similar problem but may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/3270199/2065121

Comment: Also take a look here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/LightSwitchDev11Beta/thread/eaac5474-da77-4895-91dd-8133359a87c7/

Comment: Thanks .  but that not works for me.

Comment: with same connection string vs2012 connection not work but vs2010 is working fine.
I need to work with vs2012 .

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support TLS 1.2. Update SQL Server **or configure TLS/SSL settings in the docker image/client environment to connect with TLS 1.0.** 
Modify /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf. It will contain following:

    ...
    [system_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1
    CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#possible-reasons-and-solutions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the error was produced by the antivirus