# Compiling ASP.NET project versus NET4.0 with NET4.5 installed

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET project that **was working** correctly compiled with Visual Studio 2010 and NET4.0.

Then I have installed VS Express 2012 and **NET4.5** and I always get an Exception trying to open a SqlConnection.

**Can I have some chance to recompile my project targeting NET4.0 (so without disinstalling 4.5) and have it working?**

In VS Express 2012 I have this web.config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

The referenced assemblies correctly target the v4.0, for example:

```
Assembly System.Data
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll
```

**EDIT 2**
As this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/04/12/new-reference-assemblies-location.aspx and also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543850/1012244 explains very well, there is a BIG difference betweeen Referenced Assemblies (*folder contains those assemblies that ship with the x.xx Framework which are useful for referencing during the design and build of new components*) and Runtime scenario (*At runtime, these components will still be loaded from the GAC in most cases*).

<strike>However, when I run the project I always get the Exception, as if the project actually was using NET4.5... Why?</strike>

PS. If I deploy this project on a production server machine with only NET4.0 installed, the connection is fine. 
(*This is clear now: Installing Net4.5 essentially **replaces** Net4.0*)

**UPDATED QUESTION -
Can I have some chance to recompile my project targeting an OLD NET4.0 .dll (System.Data.dll in my case) instead of the new Net4.5 dll?**

---

**EDIT - Additional info**

At this MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx I found:

> If you determine that a change in the .NET Framework 4.5 has broken your application, check the Runtime Settings Schema to determine whether you can use a runtime setting in your application configuration file to restore the previous behavior.

Could this help me? And how?

Comment: Whats the "Exception" ? Try to solve the problem not to go back, from the moment you have 4.5, forget the 4.0, is not exist any more.

Comment: The Exception is SqlException:
    A connection was successfully established with the server, 
but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Comment: @Aristos I have posted another thread for it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911681/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)