# Unable to access database from iis

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I developed one web service which simply returns some names from `sql database`. When I compiled this webservice from visual studio web server, the service is working fine and I am able to retrieve the names from `sql database`.
I hosted the service on `iis7` on `Windows 7`. The service is running fine but is unable to get data from the database.
Iam getting the following error:

> "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.."

When I debugged my service from iis, the error is 
`connection.serverversion throws system.invalidoperationexception`...
I don have any clue how to solve this. Kindly help me in this regard.
I am using `sql server 2008`.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ

Comment: No..It dint solve my problem....my visual studio is not running when I ran this application from iis. Even i checked the web server service..it did not exist...

Comment: The user of the app pool of iis can access/read the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Potential solutions:

1- Run `netsh Winsock reset` command. Probably it will fix your issue.

Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/423013/sql-an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake/487139#487139

2-  Make sure your connectionstring deos NOT include those:

```
Encrypt=True
Persist Security Info=True
```

3- Save your changes and restart Visual Studio. Restart your IIS.

4- Start SQL Server Browser in your "Services" (in the control panel).

5 - Make sure there is enough RAM to run the web service.