# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Today I could not log into my local SQL Server 2012 instance with the following error message

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.

> provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An internal error occurred.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893792)

I found many similar questions here and on the forums, but nothing helped. Please notice that in my case it just says

> 0 - An internal error occurred

- There are no errors in Event Viewer;
- I don't use Encrypted Connections;
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, `Force Protocol Entryption` is set to `False`, `Trust Server Certificate` is set to `Yes` (Originally it was `No`, but in both cases it didn't work);
- I CAN connect to SQL Server using [UDL](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/65525.aspx);
- I tried to re-install SQL Server with all related components;
- Tried to uninstall .NET 4.5;
- In SQL Management Studio, in connection properties, Encrypt Connection is unchecked.

It worked fine yesterday, I have not installed any software since then.

Comment: Please see if this helps:

http://serverfault.com/questions/423013/sql-an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake

Comment: No, it does not help. There is a meaningful exception detail in this question - provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.  Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are you using NT Security or SQL server security?

Comment: Try looking at the ring buffers for more info - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/20/connectivity-troubleshooting-in-sql-server-2008-with-the-connectivity-ring-buffer.aspx

Comment: If you can connect via UDL, are you able to query any of the tables?  In particular, does SELECT @@SERVERNAME return the correct server name?

Comment: Access to port 1433 ? Did you configured the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access. [See this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)

Comment: I am getting the same thing, but it is not consistent.  Is that what you experienced?

Comment: We see this error very rarely and intermittently with powershell scripts and it works the next time we run the script

Answer (score 6):

check that TCP/IP protocol is not enabled for clients. Without TCP/IP protocol you can not access the sql server from other clients. Following is the method to enable the protocol.

Go to the: **Start**-->**Programs**-->**SQL Server**--> **Configuration Tools**-->**SQL Configuration Manager**.

Expand the **SQL Network Configuration** and click on the **PROTOCOLS** node

Right click on **TCP/IP** and open up the **PROPERTIES** panel

Select the **IP ADDRESS** tab

http://sqlanddotnetdevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/07/a-connection-was-successfully.html

Answer (score 5):

I got this error connecting to localhost with the newest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Turns out that Microsoft really wants you to encrypt your database, for security.

This can be fixed client side by changing the connection string, by adding an `Encrypt=False` parameter, eg:

```
SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;
```

See [Rick strah's blog post on the subject](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Dec/07/Connection-Failures-with-MicrosoftDataSqlClient-4-and-later)

Answer (score 3):

In our case it was the problem with the SSL/TLS. We just disabled tls 1.0 to make sure we were compliant with PCI DSS but it stopped SQL Server. Then we had to install one update from Microsoft and then did the disable thing using IISCrypto instead of using the registry. Here's the steps we followed:
https://www.itechtics.com/connection-successfully-established-error-occured-pre-login-handshake/

Answer (score 1):

In our case same error occurred due to spn not set.Try checking if spn is set. As others suggested in comments you can see ring buffer entries which holds more info .if you are able to repro more often try running netmon or wireshark in parallel

Answer (score 0):

None of this stuff worked for me.. in the end I had to install the cumulative update for SQL Server 2014 SP1

[SQL Server Cumulative Updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was fixed by adding "Encrypt=False" like this:

```
    Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=*YOUR_DATABASE*;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False
```

Answer (score -2):

Disable TLS 1.2 protocol and enabled 1.0 /1.1 . Re-installed SQL server post restarting the server

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but nobody should leave TLS 1.0 enabled anymore. It's vulnerable with a capital "V."