# EFCore MAC - Unable to find an entry point named 'AppleCryptoNative_SslCreateContext'

Tags: ef-core-2.1

when running

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../webapi/webapi.WebAPI.csproj
```

on my MAC 10.13.5

I get this error -

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'AppleCryptoNative_SslCreateContext' in shared library 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple'.
   at Interop.AppleCrypto.SslCreateContext(Int32 isServer)
   at System.Net.SafeDeleteSslContext.CreateSslContext(SafeFreeSslCredentials credential, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.SafeDeleteSslContext..ctor(SafeFreeSslCredentials credential, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteContext& context, SecurityBuffer inputBuffer, SecurityBuffer outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

...

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

I originally thought this was my local docker database was not available but when connecting to new database instance it still occurs, this was working yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst typing this I came across this, but thought would just add the answer as someone on a MAC EF Core install may miss that also when searching -

[A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)

**Cleaning my project (I personally deleted all the folders) and rebuilding, sorted it!**