# Ubuntu 22.04 + Jetbrains Rider cannot run integration tests

Tags: .net, xunit.net, rider

Hello i'm a new user of ubuntu (installed version 22.04) and i have problems with it from the start... Currently i am struggling with running integration tests with Jetbrains Rider (I run the application without any problems and connect to this database).

The error that i have is:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(Boolean isAsync, Boolean isApm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)

System.TypeInitializationException
The type initializer for 'SslMethods' threw an exception.
at Interop.OpenSsl.AllocateSslContext(SslProtocols protocols, SafeX509Handle certHandle, SafeEvpPKeyHandle certKeyHandle, EncryptionPolicy policy, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteSslContext..ctor(SafeFreeSslCredentials credential, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)

System.TypeInitializationException
The type initializer for 'Ssl' threw an exception.
at Interop.Ssl.SslV2_3Method()
at Interop.Ssl.SslMethods..cctor()

System.TypeInitializationException
The type initializer for 'SslInitializer' threw an exception.
at Interop.Ssl..cctor()

Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException
error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name
at Interop.SslInitializer..cctor()
```

Ubuntu 22.04, .dotnet 5.0.213, Rider 2022.1

Anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: Looks like a certificate issue, maybe you're not trusting your server's certificate

Comment: well maybe, but its weird coz i can connect by app or Rider database explorer so why i cant by tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is probably due to the OpenSSL config. I had a simlar problem and resolved it with this command:

```
sed -i 's/openssl_conf = openssl_init/#openssl_conf = openssl_init/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

See
[Commit on github](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/pull/5496/commits/8bbc73d575c7b84932148a82bf2aa7a6c10ea5aa)
and
[Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27792)

for more details.

Comment: Wow that's it! It totally helps, thank you very much! It is my first time with ubuntu so i can't figure it out by myself :D

Comment: Connecting to MSSQL in Ubuntu 22.04 and this solved the issue, thanks

Comment: Do I have to restart a service afterwards?

Comment: Not that I can recall. You just need to reconnect to the database. This file is read by the JavaVM on demand.

Comment: Pretty strange problem, with efcore it was working, instead with Npgsql directly is was firing the error... Does anybody knows if this is originated by rider build or something else? Inside a docker container i didn't find any issue.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22 and resolved now. Thank you for much

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add to your connection string: Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True". Of course, that is an only a temporary solution and that can be made only for tests.

Comment: I tried to use this in connection string but sadly, it didnt help :(