# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake TCP Provider, error: 35

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)) from Xubuntu 22.04 and .NET 6.0:

```cs
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=MyDb;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;ENCRYPT=false;TrustServerCertificate=true");
```

When trying to use the connection I get this error:

```bash
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
---- System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException : Authentication failed, see inner exception.
-------- Interop+OpenSsl+SslException : SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
------------ Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException : error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
```

As you can see from the connection string I already tried `Encrypt=false` and `TrustServerCertificate=true`.

I also tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137669/90800:

```bash
sed -i 's/openssl_conf = openssl_init/#openssl_conf = openssl_init/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I also tried this one:

```bash
MinProtocol=TLSv1 CipherString=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 dotnet run
```

**Update**:

It works without modifications from a Windows client.

**Update**:

I changed `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` from this:

```ini
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

to this:

```ini
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Now the error is:

```bash
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

This

```ini
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Causes this:

```bash
Interop+OpenSsl+SslException
SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
   at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)

Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException
error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

**Update**:

There must be an option that works because from the same machine I can connect to the database using DataGrip with the jTds driver.

**Update**:

```ini
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Result:

```
Interop+OpenSsl+SslException
SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
   at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)


Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException
error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

**Update** (from https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/567):

```bash
openssl s_client -tls1 -connect server:1433
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

**Update**:

These changes have been made to the registry:

```ini
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

"Enabled"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]

"Enabled"=dword:00000000

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]

"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

**Update**:

I also installed the root CA certificate like this:

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
sudo cp local-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

**Update**:

More `openssl` output:

```bash
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    16 03 01 00 74
>>> TLS 1.1, Handshake [length 0074], ClientHello
write to 0x55971383cef0 [0x55971384e1b0] (121 bytes => 121 (0x79))
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
read from 0x55971383cef0 [0x559713844f93] (5 bytes => -1)
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3/TLS write client hello
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 121 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1658171132
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
read from 0x55971383cef0 [0x559713798600] (8192 bytes => 0)
```

Comment: `ENCRYPT=false` doesn't help if the server has Forced Encryption on. And SQL2008 doesn't support TLS1.2 unless you install the correct patch https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe

Comment: @Charlieface I will try to get this patch installed.

Comment: @Charlieface installing the patch didn't fix it.

Comment: You also need the associated patches for the base operating system that SQL Server is running on. Which version of Windows is it? A Wireshark trace would help: see what ciphers the Server Hello and Client Hello are trying to negotiate

Comment: @Charlieface It's Windows Server 2008 R2 so it should be this update, right? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Comment: Correct, you also need to follow the instructions to enable it in the registry, in particular the `SChannel` settings

Comment: Thanks, will tell the admins tomorrow and keep you posted.

Comment: I've updated the question regarding ``SChannel` registry settings.

Comment: So just to confirm: you have put in those registry settings on the Windows server that is running SQL Server, and it has the latest update for Windows Server 2008, as well as the security patch for SQL Server 2008, and you have restarted the server since then?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that.

Comment: I added more `openssl` debug output.

Comment: Is `openssl` itself fully up to date?

Comment: `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`

Comment: @Charlieface There has been an issue with the patch installation. After fixing it, the connection can be established. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your SQL Server machine to use TLS 1.2. Both Windows and SQL Server must be updated, or it will not work.

- For Windows itself, you are on Windows Server 2008 R2, which needs [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) at a minimum, really you should update to the latest build. **Ensure you set the relevant registry settings also.**
- For SQL Server, you need to get [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2008-sp4-gdr-january-6-2018-32b923c1-7af9-5c4b-5b3d-3522cab972fe) at a minimum. You must also be on the [SP4 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2979596-sql-server-2008-service-pack-4-release-information-192e37f2-2fbb-9505-44f2-2ef78861cbde) before you do this.

**I *strongly* recommend you move to newer versions of Windows and SQL Server.** Both versions that you have are heavily out-of-date and not receiving the latest security fixes, some of which are very serious.

Comment: The whole goal of this project is to get rid of the old database.