# XAMPP MySQL Error During Pre-login Handshake

Tags: mysql, asp.net, xampp

I am running an ASP.NET site locally, through which I am connecting to a local MySQL server run through XAMPP. However, every time I attempt to connect to MySQL, I receive the following error:`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.)`
I have verified that the user ID and password are correct. I have also tried a number of solutions from this thread: [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ).
It's worth noting that this code was previously working with an MSSQL server with an identical setup. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I was using System.Data.SqlClient, which only supports MSSQL. In order to use MySql, I had to install the packages MySql.Data and MySqlConnector and convert to the datatypes from those packages.