# Logging into sql server 2008 and/or reporting services using a windows login

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have my sql server 2008 setup with mixed mode authentication.  I went into sql server and added a new login and referenced an active directory user.

But it seems like all the windows authentication based stuff only ever works with whatever was used to login to the operating system. So I'm outside their domain on my machine and I can't connect. But even if I remote desktop into the server itself, using a seperate remote desktop login, even on that machine, I can't login using the active directory user since in the login box, if I choose window auth, I can't specifiy a different name, and sql server auth says invalid login. I don't see how to supply a windows username and password JUST when logging into sql server.

And also, what about my .net apps?  I don't want to hardcode a sql server auth username/password into my encrypted connection string, i want to hard code a windows active directory username/password into the connection string.

And then reporting services,  aarrghhh.. Does reporting servies ONLY work with windows logins?  If so, then I'm stuck with getting the above working. If not, how do I configure a sql server login to also let me access all our reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really broad question; I'll give a survey of some of the different topics you address. I work in a hosting provider and we have many domains with no trusts between them, so I deal with this on a daily basis.

Yes, SQL Server Windows authentication really wants to use the credentials running the client application. You can work around this with the [RunAs /netonly switch:](http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/10/12/tip-how-to-run-programs-as-a-domain-user-from-a-non-domain-computer/)

> runas /netonly /user:domain\username “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe”

Authentication for .NET apps is a big topic. Lots of options and chapters, if not books have been written on this.

Regarding Reporting Services: most of this access is through a browser. So this will use whatever credentials you supply to your browser. In IE this is controlled through the security zones and settings of whether your current credentials should be used or if you should be prompted.

Comment: runas is not an option. Basically, we want to authenticate the user, but we don't want users to be able to get into the database directly themselves using any other type of sql tool. We also need our app to serve up reports using reproting services but we don't want users getting into that directly either.  I was thinking that I could use a SPECIFIC hardcoded encrypred windows auth for both the db and reportin services but it seems to me that using windows authentication is just completely out at this point.

Comment: You are changing your question: these are lots of additional requirements. What exactly is your question now? How to hard code credentials? How to guaranty a connection comes from a specific binary? I'm honestly not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree, maybe the question changed. Also, maybe I answered my own question. And the answer is that it is impossible to hard code WINDOWS credentials into a connection string?

Comment: Correct: Microsoft connection strings do not allow Windows credentials to be stored there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/sql-server-connection-string-trusted-connection-true-issue

Answer (score 0):

Some clues:

- If you're external user and SQL Server is in mixed mode it will be easier for you to have SQL login not mapped to AD user (so you use SQL auth and not Windows auth). You may have two SQL Logins - one for Windows auth, second for SQL auth.
- If you don't your .NET apps have hard coded passwords use Windows auth and Trusted Connection mode in your ConnectionString. If your .NET app is a service create dedicated AD user then create SQL Login mapped to this AD user. Give your SQL User mapped to SQL Login permissions whatever it needs. Run service in context of dedicated AD user. If app is directly executed by users (.EXE file) also use Trusted Connection. Create AD security group for your app users. Create SQL "group" Login mapped to this AD group. Give your SQL "group" User mapped to SQL Login permissions whatever it needs.
- It's not possible to provide login and password for SQL Login with Windows auth in ConnectionString. You use TrustedConnection for Windows auth and login/password for SQL auth.
- You may play with switching context inside SQL session - `EXECUTE AS`, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx