# How can I use one Windows account for ASP.Net impersonation, and a different windows account for a Sql Server trusted connection in the same app?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-4.0, active-directory, impersonation

I have an ASP NET web app that uses identity impersonation. However, there is an SQL connection string that I must use with SQL Server to retrieve data that relies on a Trusted Connection. Is there any way I can specify a Windows account to communicate with SQL, but still use impersonation in the rest of my web app? If it makes a difference, this application uses .net 4.0, connecting to SQL 2008.

I've read several posts already on SO (including this one - [When using Trusted_Connection=true and SQL Server authentication, will this effect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe)), but I haven't found a cohesive answer to my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use SQL Server Authentication, instead of Windows Authentication?

Comment: Only way I've ever done this is with SQL Server Auth like Rowland suggests.  Have the SQL user/pass in the connection string, allow impersonation elsewhere.

Comment: Sys Admin policy thus-far has been to use dedicated windows AD groups, and apply appropriate SQL roles to those groups.  This is the first web app we've had that uses impersonation, hence why we havent had the issue yet.  So you're correct, SQL Auth would resolve this issue, but right now we're trying to stick with windows auth instead..

Comment: The other option would be an SOA, with the webserver calling back to a non-impersonating service...

Comment: Thanks Rowland, that's the direction I was thinking as well...  Thanks @Garrison as well, ultimately I just needed confirmation that there was no "easy" way to do this, before I started to head down the SOA path...

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I wanted to be sure that the same rules apply now, that Identity Impersonation on a web app will pass user credentials to a sql database using Windows AD authentication.  Based on the comments above, that seems to be the case.  Thanks everyone for their time, should any future readers see this Q&A and say "Eric's wrong and he's an idiot!", please feel free to correct me accordingly