# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2012 (connection string issue?)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have been searching through SO and found a connection string that seems to be what I need.

However, it does not work.

I use SQL Server 2012 Express and I need my application to connect (with no credentials). I am using the following con.string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

However, the server does not respond.

Comment: Is your database instance setup to allow windows authentication? More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **either** use the proper SQL Server **Express** - then use this connection string:

```
server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

(*use just `(local)` - **not** `(localdb)`*)

or you use **LocalDB** (which is a "run-on-demand" version of SQL Server Express), in that case, use:

```
server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

The difference:

- SQL Server **Express** proper is a **server-based** solution, which is installed and runs as a Windows service all the time
- SQL Server Express **LocalDB** is a run-on-demand version of SQL Server Express, which only gets started up when you need it (e.g. in debugging inside Visual Studio 2012/2013)