# Change the SqlConnection,Credentials property

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

So i have a login page and i have to implement a validation: 'If the user is "sa" then it should connect to the Database using that users credentials', which means i have to modify the credentials of my `SqlConnection` object:

```
        if(username.Equals("sa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach(char character in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(character);
            }

            securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
            var credentials = new SqlCredential(username, securePassword);
            sqlConn.Close();
            sqlConn.Credential = credentials;

            sqlConn.Open();

            return true;
        }
```

But im getting an exception in `sqlConn.Credential = credentials;` even though the property is not `readonly`

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot use Credential with UserID, UID, Password, or PWD connection string keywords.

Is there any other way to change the `Credentials` property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe

Comment: I dont have `integrated security` in my `connectionString`. It seems like you can modify the credentials if the `SqlConnection` has an user and password, I used a workaround to solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can modify the credentials if the `SqlConnection` has an user and password. I use the examples of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/03/09/safer-passwords-with-sqlcredential.aspx) tutorial to make it work:

```
        if (username.Equals("sa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Server={0};Initial Catalog={1};", sqlConn.DataSource, sqlConn.Database)))
            {
                var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
                foreach (char character in password)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(character);
                }

                securePassword.MakeReadOnly();

                var credentials = new SqlCredential(username, securePassword);
                conn.Credential = credentials;

                conn.Open();

                return true;
            }
        }
```

Since i couldn't modify the `Credential` property i made a copy of my `SqlConnection` object without the `username` and `password` in the `connectionString`. That way i can add new `Credential` later. Hope this helps anyone else facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

## SqlConnection.Credential Property

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.credential(v=vs.110).aspx

An InvalidOperationException exception will be raised:

- If Credential is set on an open connection.
- If Credential is set when Context Connection=true.
- If Credential is set when Integrated Security = true.
- If Credential is set when the connection string uses Password.
- If Credential is set when the connection string uses UserID.

Comment: Yeah, in my case it was because of the two last options. I posted the way i solved it but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`,

```
string connectString = "Data source=.;initial catalog=yourDB; 
                        User Id=user; Password=password";
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder (connectString);
SqlConnection sqlConn= new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Then in your method,

```
 builder.Remove("User Id");
 builder.Remove("Password");
 // builder.Remove("integrated security"); if you had used
 sqlConn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thats a nice way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: It's unfortunate that SqlConnectionStringBuilder provides convenient and strongly-typed way to *set* properties on a connection string, but in order to *unset* them, string constants "User Id" and "Password" have to be used. On a positive side, this is somewhat compensated by the fact that the argument to builder.Remove() is case insensitive, and it also accepts alternative names of keywords; i.e., for example, the following also work: builder.Remove("user id"); builder.Remove("uid").