# SQL Connection String appsettings.json

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

**This is my connection string**

```
{
  "Data": {
    "PhotoGalleryConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=WINDOWS-B7MJR5T\\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=sa;password=allah;Database=PhotoGallery;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  }
}
```

**And I am facing this exception**

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot open database "PhotoGallery" requested
>   by the login. The login failed.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using this connection string?

Comment: Why do you have a connection string in a JSON object?

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious that this is bad practice to store connection strings in Json. You are best in storing it in an `App.config` or `Web.config` file and referencing it by key where necessary

Comment: And, looking at some possible issues: Isn't the instance to use meant to be declared in the format `Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;` (not `Server=...`? And have an `Initial Catalog=YourDbName` set, too?

Comment: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<PhotoGalleryContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:PhotoGalleryConnection:ConnectionString"]));

Comment: I have tried Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName and Initial Catalog=YourDbName but it's also not working

Comment: Migrating Configuration From ASP.NET MVC 5 to MVC 6 we use connection string in json format.For reference http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingconfig.html

Answer (score 7):

It should work after You delete Trusted_Connection=True; from connection string.

> If you specify either Trusted_Connection=True; or Integrated
>   Security=SSPI; or Integrated Security=true; in your connection string 
>   THEN (and only then) you have Windows Authentication happening. Any
>   user id= setting in the connection string will be ignored.  Found in here: [When using Trusted_Connection=true and SQL Server authentication, will this effect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe)

Comment: I have deleted Trusted_Connection=True.It's also not working.How can i fit SQL server authentication in this connection string

Comment: when  using this{
  "Data": {
    "PhotoGalleryConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=WINDOWS-B7MJR5T\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PhotoGallery;User Id=sa;pwd=allah"
    }
  }
}   I get this An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: Removing Trusted_Connection=True fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please search service in window menu]

Please search services in the window menu, it will show you the local services then go to SQL server services and refresh all, then go to the SQL server management studio and by using SQL authentication please provide username and password, you will be able to use the SQL server. for appsetting.json update, trusted_connection is used for window authentication not for SQL server authentication by using username and password