# Is there any way of using integrated authentication in SQL Server connection string of asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have a SQL server in a Windows Server which can be accessed by using both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication. I have a username and password for SQL based authentication. I am using this SQL Server database in an asp.net core application in a linux server. Currently, I am using the username and password of the SQL Server in the connection string (in appSettings.json) to connect to this database. But, I don't want to expose this username and password by putting it in clear text in this json file. Is there any other way of connecting to SQL Server database without using username and password in asp.net core application appSettings.json. I came across certificate based authentication somewhere but couldn't find a way to use it.

Comment: domain auth should work fine as long as the asp-net service is running as the intended domain account

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954500/9940803

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Sanpas that is a totally different issue.

Comment: Simply: you can turn on integrated Auth in the connection string. Then the domain identity of the executing code is used for the connection, assuming you have a proper domain setup.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the reply. Actually, I was talking about asp.net core application that is running in a linux server. The sql server is in windows server.

Comment: Ah, I see; indeed, you didn't mention that bit (until the recent edit). That changes things.