# Error: login failed for user SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using my C# code, but unable to establish the connection it keeps throwing the exception login failed for user abcdef.

When I use the same credentials to connect to DB through SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine without any issues.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn" 
         connectionString="Server=xxxx\yyyy;User ID=abcdef;Password=******;Initial Catalog=mytestDB;"/>
</connectionStrings>

string strDBCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString();
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = strDBCon;
sqlConnection.Open();
```

Comment: Does that user have permissions to the "mytestDB" db as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect and query from that DB through SSMS

Comment: Are you running ssms from your local machine?

Comment: Yes, i'm running the ssms from my local machine, but running it as a different user and then using the credentials that i've used in my connectionstring.

Comment: What context is this running in? IIS?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework in your application?

Comment: @Nitin, this is not Entity Framework.

Comment: @stuartd, it is just a small console application.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth : I know this is not Entity Framework. I was asking whether you are using Entity framework in your application somewhere else or not.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth : For this issue, I think there can be one of the two causes. 1. You are using the same connection string in EF and its still open(if this is not the case). 2. It should be an access issue as you are using different credentials for login to SSMS.

Comment: @Nitin, no there is no entity frame work in my application and the credentials are same. I still didn't find any solution for this. To keep going I ran my VS using the credentials that i've used in my connection string and added the trusted connection.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether `.ToString()` gives back the correct representation of the connection string. Anyway, that would be the correct one:

```
string strDBCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: @PeterDeme, this will not help resolve my issue and it is not going to change the way the connectionstring gets created I believe.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth can you debug the value of strDBCon? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I could see everything is correct i the strDBCon when I debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="NameOFConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=User;Password=Pwd"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then call the connection string

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOFConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use trusted connection and you should add "Trusted_Connection=True" to connection string.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=True` is for **Windows Authentication** and will cause [any Sql Sever credentials specified to be ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe)

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is for Windows Authentication