# Disable Windows Authentication while connecting into database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, sqlconnection

I have the problem with connection into database with asp.net core 2.0.

There is my connection string :

```
  "ApplicationConfiguration": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=***; Database=***; User Id=***; Password=***; Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated Security=True;"
  }
```

I'm getting connection string properly so it's not an issue. :(
In the database I have mixed authentication. So whenever I'm connect to database it's using props from connection string and using Windows Authentication as well. Why I know that ? Because on my pc It's work fine because I'm 'registered' to database. But whenever my friend trying to connect into database he gets "Login failed" error but his domain Login is displayed not from connection string.

Comment: Look at this here. I guess it should explain why :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION :

Just remove from your connection string:

```
Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated Security=True;
```

Thanks to : Schadensbegrenzer
Explanation : [When using Trusted_Connection=true and SQL Server authentication, will this effect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe)