# .Net Entity Core Update-Database gives System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string, sql-server-2016

I am able to connect to SQL Server Management Studio with this user, but when I run
`Update-Database` from the nuget package console, I get this error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'. Error Number:18456, State:1, Class:14

**Not Working**

```
Server=(local);User Id=sa;Password=[password];Database=[Database]
```

**Working**

```
Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=True;Database=[Database];
```

What is the issue with first connection string or User ?

Comment: Nuget package console ?? I think it should be package manager console.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the connection string?

Comment: Yes, Package Manager Console.

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642508/6527049

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using Trusted\_Connection=true and SQL Server authentication, will this affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-affe)