# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication in c# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have c# application and now I am trying to connect to sql server 2012 that inside the another computer.

Here is my connection string=>

```
<add key="SP" value="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Servarname;initial catalog=DB;user id=sa;password=password;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
```

But when i run the application from client,i get this error message=>

[image]

Comment: What the error says. You can't fix that with code, it complains that *your account* isn't allowed to connect to the server, because it's not valid for that computer or domain. In fact, it says "I don't trust your domain"

Comment: If you want to connect from one machine to another, they should be in a domain and you should be using a domain account

Comment: or it needs to be set to use SQL authentication..

Comment: I connected with sa account  and if cant,how can i allow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-effe

Comment: Currently server domain and client domain are not the same.I already set the SQL Authentication in SQL server=>Properties=>Setting.

Comment: @Loran google the error, you'll see the question has already been asked and answered. NO, don't use `sa` and don't use SQL logins just because. Windows Authentication isn't broken and SQL Logins aren't as secure - where will you store the username and password? It could be there's a problem with your domain, or you tried something that shouldn't be done, like try to connect to the database using a local account from another machine

Comment: I think you should remove the `Trusted_Connection=true`.

Comment: @Loran *why* are they not the same and why did you expect that you could just connect? Did you add the account to the server as a Windows login?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I think that's a very bad idea unless you know the actual deployment environment and have ways to protect credentials and identify clients. A far better solution would be to set up trust between domains

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please let me check step by step what u said,Now i am already take 2 day for this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The connection string does not seem OK for SA account  built-in login to me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't add user account for login and can u bit explain for "connect to database using a local account from another machine"?

Comment: @Loran If you are using SA account, i.e. sql authentication and not windows authentication, then you do not need to worry about domains. Your connection string seems schizophrenic to me, because `Trusted_Connection=True` is for windows authentication, but SA account uses SQL authentication.

Comment: Check this https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @loran did you make any progress?