# C# VS 2019 SQLException: code works on Console App but not on WebForms app

Tags: c#

I am working with VS 2019 in an ASP.NET Webforms project, and I am getting the following error when I try to execute a stored procedure on a remote SQL Server database:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "AMSTSUFSS" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'AMERICAS\espinjon'.'

I can login just fine with Windows Authentication in SSMS. Also, the same code works just fine in a console application, so there must be something going on with the form, the onlick event, the post....I don't know, and this is driving me crazy now! Please help.

This is the code and it fails on the line `da.Fill(table);`:

```
private static System.Data.DataTable GetListOflocIds(SqlConnection Conn, DateTime pStartDate, DateTime pEndDate)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UBOX.SP_GetPartnerList", Conn))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = pStartDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = pEndDate;

        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 180;
        da.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Your connection string is apparently incorrect.  The issue isn't in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the connection string.

Web apps sometimes run under different users in IIS and if the connection string doesn't explicitly state that it should use windows authentication, the web server might decide to use the credentials of that user instead.

Do you have `Integrated Security=true;` in your connection string? If not, adding it might help.

Also have a look at this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642508/1936841