# Drop-Database Failed creating connection: Couldn't set trusted_connection

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, npgsql

I have a new local ASP.Net Core 6 application that uses docker and is connected to a local docker postgres container (individually run containers, not with Docker Compose). I added the Npgsql package and managed to successfully connect to it and create tables (Checked with PgAdmin). The issue is whenever I try to run 'Drop-Database' from the Package Manager Console, I get the below error:

```
Performing the operation "Drop-Database" on target "database 'Failed creating connection: Couldn't set trusted_connection (Parameter 'trusted_connection')' on server 'Failed creating connection: Couldn't set trusted_connection (Parameter 'trusted_connection')'".
```

To me this doesn't make sense because I am not using any trusted connection parameter in my connection string:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=host.docker.internal;Database=local;Username=postgres;Password=password;Include Error Detail=true"
  }
```

I have two other solutions that use docker and successfully run PMC commands to a local docker postgres container so I am not sure what is different this time. I have not found any similar resources for troubleshooting this, and specifying ['Trusted_Connection=true' or 'Integrated Security=True'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-affe) does not work.

My `Program.cs` file is unchanged from the starter project except for the below for Npgsql:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options
    .UseNpgsql(connectionString)
    .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

Please let me know if there is anything that could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was previously on a different project, I manually set the enviroment in Package Manager Console using:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Local'
```

So when trying to drop the database, it was searching for a Local appsettings connection string which did not exist on my new project. Setting the environment back to Development solved this issue for me.