# Why is EF Core using the Domain\MachineName instead of the provided connection string User Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core, connection-string

### Question

When using EF Core the SQL queries are sending the wrong username for SQL authentication.

We get Login failed for user '{DOMAIN}\{MACHINE NAME}' instead of {DOMAIN}\{User Id}

[image]

```
"Database": "Server=data.example.com;Database=example_data;Trusted_Connection=true;encrypt=no; user id=example; pwd=examplepassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

But when looking at our logs we see this

[image]

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Domain\MachineName$'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__21_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:2e167322-21d0-47ab-bc9b-8d900fec060e
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
```

We are using IIS to host this application. I don't think this should matter but we have Anonymous Authentication enabled, Windows Authentication is disabled.

### Extra Code Bits

##### Program.cs

```
using LoadingBlazorWebAssemblyApp.Server.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.ConfigureDataContexts(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsEnvironment("Test"))
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

##### DB Context Registration

```
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"), s => s.CommandTimeout(180))
            .ConfigureWarnings(warning => warning.Ignore(CoreEventId.StartedTracking))
            .LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message))
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
```

### Provider and version information

EF Core version: 7.0.3

Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.3

Target framework: .NET 7.0

Operating system: Windows Server

Comment: My guess, you are running the IIS application pool under the machine account and that's the account the connection string seems to want to use. Why does the connection string want to use this account, because of this part of the connection string, `Trusted_Connection=true;`. Remove this part of the connection string to use the credentials in the SQL string, or add the machine name IIS is using to the SQL server's permissions  ... [Trusted_Connection=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/when-using-trusted-connection-true-and-sql-server-authentication-will-this-affe).

Comment: Try adding `Integrated Security=false;` to the connection string because it sounds like its falling back on SSPI

Comment: @quaabaam - Removing the 'Trusted_Connection=true;' seemed to work. I was wondering if you explain a bit more about why this would cause the issue?

What does the trusted change that makes it force windows authentication vs a non-trusted version?

Comment: `Trusted_Connection` means using the Windows credentials of the currently logged in user (or the service account IIS is running under) to log in. If you want to specify explicit user id and password, **do not** specify `Trusted_Connection` at the same time - it will take precedence...

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for explaining! I had no idea, I thought it had something to do with SSL trust but it appears I was incorrect. Thank you very much!

Comment: Trusted Connection is useful when you don't want to put the SQL credentials in the configuration files. It can also be useful if you are developing and your user account has access to the development database.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was using the following option in my appsettings.json connection string.

`Trusted_Connection=true;`

Thank you to quaabaam and marc_s for showing me the issue and explaining the reason. Upon reading their responses I did some more research and found the following

[image: Detailed Explanation Image]

You can find this information on this page from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString